# How to store Image that is download by Picasso in android?

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I am building android application and using Picasso lib to download the image from url.

Now I wanna to download and store in app so I can use it any time any where I need it.

I am using below code to download the image

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
            .load(profilePic)
            .transform(new CircleTransform())
            .into(userimg);
```

Comment: You would have more control if you write your own asyncTask and use httpUrlConnection

Answer (score 2):

`Picasso` has a thing called `Target` to intercept a `Bitmap` as it comes in.

```
class MyTarget implements Target {

    private ImageView imageView;

    public MyTarget(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        this.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

}
```

With this you can do:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(new MyTarget(imageView));
```

And set the `Bitmap` to an `ImageView` there (in the `Target`).

Comment: Thanks @shkschneider can you help me in telling which import should I used for target

Comment: It showing the error - Class 'Anonymous class derived from Target' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'value()' in 'Target'

Comment: [Target](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Target.java) is an interface, you need to implement it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Here is my is my code that I am using - ImageView userimg = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
        Picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load(profilePic)
                .transform(new CircleTransform())
                .into(new MyTarget(userimg));

Comment: and the mytarget class but still not showing anything. can you suggested me any tutorial

Comment: The code I gave you works for me. Check for invalid `Bitmap` with `onBitmapFailed()`. Here is the documentation: https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html